# How to get id of selected row in table using javascript

Tags: javascript, django

Current student information list is being printed. Then, by selecting the checkbox and clicking the "Add Teacher" button, a function has been added so that the currently logged in name is added to the teacher column. Here, I want to apply an event to all selected rows by passing multiple values ​​to the parameter when multiple checkboxes are selected. I've been looking for it, but I can't find a solution, so please help.

urls.py

```
path('student/add_teacher/<int:id>/', views.add_teacher)
```

views.py

```
def add_teacher(request, id):
    student = Student.objects.get(pk=id)
    student.teacher = request.user.name
    student.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/student/')
```

student_list.html

```
<table id="student-list" class="maintable">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Register date</th>
              <th>Select</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          {% for student in student %}
          <tr class="text-black tr-hover table-link text-center student" student-id="{{ student.id }}">
             <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
             <td>{{ student.age }}</td>
             <td>{{ student.register_date }}</td>
             <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary addteacher">Update Teacher</button>
```

student_function.js

```
$(function () {
        $('button.addteacher').click(function (e) {
        var elem = $(".maintable input:checked").parents("tr");
        var studentID = elem.attr('student-id');
        var updateTeacher = confirm("업데이트하시겠습니까?");
        if (updateTeacher) {
            window.location.href = 'student/add_teacher/' + studentID + '/';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i notice one bug inside your code.you are putting this outside the for loop <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary addteacher">Update Teacher</button>  .i think it is better to put it inside the forloop so that for every student listed in your for loop you can add a teacher and put your "student-id" inside the button tag.with that it will be very easy to grap the student id by doing $(this).attr('student-id').

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. However, if button is placed inside a for statement, numerous buttons are output. Since this function works normally, I want to receive multiple arguments and apply an event to all of them. I found a way to request.POST.getlist('id') .

Comment: So for that you can try to use ajax to send the data to the server and remember always use POST when you are applying data to the database inside your views.py.

Comment: @lesssuccess i wrote an example how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

templates:

```
<table id="student-list" class="maintable">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Register date</th>
              <th>Select</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for student in student %}
        <tbody>
    
      <tr class="text-black tr-hover table-link text-center student" id="{{ student.pk }}">
         <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
         <td>{{ student.age }}</td>
         <td>{{ student.register_date }}</td>
      <td>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary addteacher" student-id="{{ student.pk }}">Update Teacher</button>
    </td>
<tr>
              
            </tbody>

    {% endfor %}
          </table>
```

js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.addteacher').click(function (e) {
  
        var studentID = $(this).attr('student-id');
      $.post("{% url 'add_teacher' %}",
           { 
         id:studentID 
          },
function(data, status){
  // you can do what ever you want here after success 
  $('#'+studentID).hide();
  });
         
})
</script>
```

views.py

```
def add_teacher(request):
    student_id = request.POST.get('id')
    // you can add some extra logic here
    student = Student.objects.get(pk=int(student_id))
    student.teacher = request.user.name
    student.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/student/')
```

urls.py:

```
path('student/add_teacher/', views.add_teacher,name='add_teacher')
```

this is just an example how you can do it.